# I keep getting 'Host key verification failed.' when calling `ssh` from PHP on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, apache, ssh

I have set up a password-less login from my laptop (OS X) to my dev server (Linux) - this works fine (using `~/.ssh/id_rsa` private key, and having put the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into the servers `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file). So far, so good.

However, I am trying to connect to the server from within a PHP script. The Apache server supposedly runs as the `_www` user, and I have added the necessary hosts line to `~_www/.ssh/known_hosts` without solving the problem.

I am feeling that there is something basic and fundamental about how Apache on OSX works that I am missing - any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: I have confirmed that `_www` is indeed the currently logged in user, and the home directory is indeed `/Library/WebServer`. I added the known host to `/Library/WebServer/.ssh/known_hosts`, and I also forgot to mention that the private key file has been made readable by the _www user, and when I call the script I call `ssh -i /path/to/private.key`.

Comment: First thing I would do is check the permissions. Also, set up passwordless login for _www, not yourself. That means that _www needs rsa keys. I just ran a php script, exec'd "whoami" and it spit out my username. Ran it from a script on a webpage and it game up "apache". So, you can print the result of exec("whoami") to ensure you have the correct user.

Comment: Thanks, @kainaw, I added a new section above with some updated info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - the `.ssh` directory in `/Library/WebServer` was owned by `root:wheel` (like the other files and directories in that directory, thus hiding the fact in plain view...). I changed ownership to `_www:wheel`, and it works like it should now! Thanks, and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No problem. Permissions and ownership are very hard to deal with in this particular case. I wrote a script to ensure all ownerships and permissions on both ends of the SSH are set properly because I got annoyed with it.